# Find the probability that less than two tokens out of 20 will not operate the machine

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Circular metal tokens are used to operate a washing machine in a laundromat. The diameters of the tokens are known to be normally distributed. Only tokens with diameters between 1.94 cm and 2.06 cm will operate the machine.

Find the probability that less than two tokens out of 20 will not operate the machine.

Do I use binomial distribution for this? Because it only has two outcomes and its probability is independent of each other.

[image]

Comment: I got different values. $0.3774$ if I don’t use binomial and $0.7359$ if I use binomial.

Comment: The numerical value is absolutely uninformative; what matters is the calculation you did.

Comment: For what its worth, you have too little information in the post.  "*Diameters of the tokens are known to be normally distributed*"  With what mean and what standard deviation?

Comment: Having gone and looked at the edit history, we see the now missing information that $2\%$ of the coins are too small and $3\%$ of the coins are too large.  In other words, $5\%$ of the coins don't work.  The fact that it is normally distributed no longer matters (*though we could have bothered to try to find the mean and standard deviation if we insisted*).  So then, yes we use the binomial distribution and we get the answer is approximately $0.73584$.  "*I get 0.3774 if I don't use binomial*"  I have no idea what calculation you tried to use there, but it is wrong.

Comment: *Perhaps* you got that number by looking at $20\times 0.05\times 0.95^{19}\approx 0.3773536$ but that is still using the binomial distribution but is very specifically the probability of **exactly one** coin being the wrong size and ignores the possibility of no coins being the wrong size.  It was the right answer to the wrong question.

Comment: Oh. I apologize. 
Not using binomial: $(0.95)^20\times (0.05)^0 + (0.95)^{19}\times (0.05)^1=0.3585$. Because we want all 20 to be successful or 19 to be successful. 
Using binomial $X~B(20, 0.95)$: $P(X=0)+P(X=1)=\binom{20}{20}(0.95)^{20}(0.05)^0+\binom{20}{19}(0.95)^{19}(0.05)^1=0.7359$.

Comment: $(0.95)^{20}\times (0.05)^0 + (0.95)^{19}\times (0.05)^1$ is the probability that either no coins were the wrong size, or the probability that *very specifically the last* coin was the wrong size but ignores the possibility of it there having been one coin the wrong size but it having been the first coin, or the second coin, or the third coin, etc... rather than very specifically the last coin.

Comment: Ohh I see, thank you, @JMoravitz and I apologize for not including an important information.

Comment: So in answer to your question, yes, you use the binomial distribution for (b) but you have to use it carefully.  0.73584 looks correct